# Изменить переменную в дочернем компоненте через родительский

Tags: javascript, vue.js, frontend

В дочернем компоненте есть переменная которую нужно очищать через родительский компонент. К примеру чтобы при нажатии на кнопку в род. компоненте очищалась переменная в дочернем. Как можно это реализовать?
Вот пример:

Родитель

```html
<template>
  <div>
     <button @click="changeVar">
        btn
     </button>
     <Child/>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Child from "@/components/Child";

export default {
  components: {
    Child
  },
  methods: {
     changeVar(){
        // Менять переменную в доч. компоненте 
     }
  },
};
</script>
```

Ребенок

```html
<template>
  <div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "Child",
  data() {
    return {
      var: "", // Переменная которую нужно менять
    };
  },

};
</script>
```

Comment: Почитайте про $emit https://metanit.com/web/vuejs/4.11.php

Comment: @Алексей, emit работает в обратном направлении - от ребенка к родителю.

Comment: Передайте переменную, ребенку, в качестве props. При необходимости, создайте watcher или computed-свойство.

Answer (score 1):

Используйте `props` - это способ передачи данных из родительского компонента ниже в дочерний.

Для этого достаточно **передать** данные дочернему компоненту в качестве атрибутов, при его использовании  **из родительского компонента**:

```
<test :variable="variable"></test>
```

И обязательно **объявить** эти данные **в дочернем компоненте** в `props`

```
...
props: ['variable'],
...
```

По умолчанию все данные, объявленные в `props` дочернего компонента являются реактивными и однонаправленными. Будьте внимательны: при попытке изменить эти данные из дочернего компонента вы получите сообщение о том, что это плохая практика. `props` используется для передачи данных дочернему компоненту и обеспечивает их реактивное обновление, в случае обновления данных в родительском компоненте. Если вам нужна двусторонняя привязка данных - лучше посмотреть в сторону [v-model](https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-model)

Более подробно - [Входные параметры](https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html)

Наглядный пример:

```js
const test = Vue.component('test', {
  props: ['variable'],
  template: `<div>{{ variable }}</div>`
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      variable: false
    }
  },
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <test :variable="variable"></test>
  <button @click="variable=!variable">Изменить из родителя</button>
</div>
```